# Graphics coprocessor power usage increases drastically during thermal throttle; how can I prevent this?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, cooling, intel-graphics

I have an MSI GE62-2QD laptop running Windows 10 v1607 (build 14393.0) with an Optimus graphics configuration (GTX960m discrete and Intel HD Graphics 5600 on an i7-5700hq).

Occasionally, the laptop encounters overheating (about 90 degrees) and begins to throttle by limiting CPU frequency to about 800MHz, until cores drop to 89 degrees. However, when throttling occurs (for example in a game that is using the NVidia GPU), the Intel XTU utility reports that the power consumed by the Intel graphics coprocessor jumps dramatically, from 1-4W to about 18W. This additional power consumption causes the temperature of the die to continue to rise, making it hard to break out of the overheat situation.

I've already tried to clean and replace fans, as well as re-seat the heatsink with new MX4 thermal paste (cleaning all surfaces with the recommended cleaning processes), which has kept temperatures slightly lower but still causes occasional thermal throttle events.

This additional Intel GPU power consumption does not make sense, since I'm not running any GPU-intensive processes that utilize it, and it shouldn't be receiving any additional load. According to Intel XTU, the graphics frequency is as low as 200MHz during the throttle events, and running GPU stress tests on the Intel GPU doesn't lead to such high power consumption when the system is not throttling. Additionally, on Linux (dual-boot), the system recovers from throttle events almost immediately, leading me to conclude that the issue is not present at that time.

I've attempted to use Throttlestop's BD PROCHOT flag (as well as other parameters such as max graphics frequency, graphics undervoltage, etc) to no avail. The NVidia GPU (unaffected by this) has no cooling problems.

Is there any known fix for this?

Comment: BD PROCHOT? https://www.techpowerup.com/download/techpowerup-throttlestop/

Comment: @bwDraco I'll try it, thanks. However, the Intel GPU is not the cause of the overheating; if it continued to operate at the same clock/voltage/power the throttle would not be an issue. Will edit post once I test this.

Comment: @bwDraco No luck, with BD PROCHOT runaway power usage still occurs once the thermal threshold is tripped. Attempted updating all Intel drivers as well, to no avail.

Comment: If you click the Intel HD Graphics driver tray icon, select Graphics Properties, 3D tab, do you have a performance slider that you can set to less?

Comment: @harrymc yes, and I have tried setting it to all possible settings.

Comment: Does it happen only when you do certain actions such as play games? Does it happen if you boot in Safe mode?

Comment: @harrymc It's triggered by anything that causes heating to occur to a sufficient extent. I have not yet verified whether it occurs in safe mode because I do not have any applications that can cause heavy heat and can run in safe mode.

Comment: There are only the two usual possibilities: Hardware or software. It's either caused by some software product overusing the CPU which is easily seen in Task Manager, or your CPU fan-control is defective. You could trace the CPU fan via [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php). You could also try to [disable Intel HD](http://itstillworks.com/disable-builtin-vga-card-msi-8353.html).

Comment: @harrymc The fan control is not the issue. The fans are already being driven at the highest speed possible, using a hardware-level override, and even if the override is not being used, the fans reach maximum speed. The issue is characterized as an issue with power management of the CPU/iGPU pair, where a measurement of the current being *physically* drawn by the CPU/GPU die through its voltage regulator, is increasing inappropriately after a throttle event occurs. Additionally, the instructions you mention don't apply to an Optimus laptop, since all video *must* go through the iGPU.

Comment: @harrymc That being said, if there's a software fix I'm comfortable doing kernel-level programming needed to communicate with the appropriate power management interfaces, but cannot find documentation with regard to this. However, all common causes such as fan control/poor thermal interface conductivity and the like have already been ruled out. While I don't doubt that a marginal improvement in the thermal paste or fan power may help the issue, it does not at all address the root cause that the CPU power management behaves inappropriately and counterproductively during a throttle event.

Comment: Try to examine CPU usage when this happens using the [Resource Monitor](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-use-windows-10s-resource-monitor-to-track-memory-usage/). Did you replace the CPU fan with a better one or the same model? Updated all drivers? There are many reports about your model running too hot for extended usage. Finally the real solution might be just to improve the cooling. Maybe for some reason the video driver uses both GPUs.

Comment: @harrymc There are no other choices for fan for this laptop; I have replaced it with one that had better bearings than the previous one. All drivers are up-to-date. CPU usage is fine (although the throttle, of course, limits the CPU to 800MHz meaning that applications end up requiring more CPU time). I've verified that other laptops do not have runaway consumption if they do throttle for any reason. Regardless of whether I can improve cooling in an economical manner, the CPU PM should not be doing this.

Comment: Is the BIOS the latest version? I hope there is no overclocking. If the problem is a faulty CPU thermal sensor for BD PROCHOT, try to disable it in the BIOS "Intel Adaptive Thermal Monitor", but this is dangerous if the overheating is real. In any case, if you have other laptops that are identical in hardware and software and do not show this problem, then I think that you have a faulty motherboard.

Comment: @harrymc BIOS is updated, there is no overclocking; I don't have control over Intel Adaptive Thermal Monitor in my BIOS; other laptops are not identical but have the same CPU model and do not suffer from this.

Comment: Do you see much usage of the CPU during a spike?

Comment: @harrymc not particularly beyond the previous load. However, throttling drops frequency, causing the current load to saturate all available cpu time.

Comment: The last test I can thing of is to boot in Safe mode (maybe with network). Without more info, and given what you are saying, I don't have any more ideas except that your model has either a bad motherboard or its cooling is insufficient by design (improvements exist for mitigating such laptop problems). Windows may be driving the motherboard less efficiently than Linux.

Comment: @harrymc As I've already mentioned the applications that I need to run on this machine are incompatible with Safe Mode (even with networking). Many of them are scientific applications that require an NVidia GPU present for CUDA (and others are games, with the same issues). However, "normal" applications still encounter throttling issues if they hit the thermal limit. If Windows is driving the motherboard/chipset/PM interface less efficiently, would you have a reference that I could use to develop my own kernel-mode software workaround to drive it properly?

Comment: That's a tall order and the info is probably impossible to find. Are you using the latest [MSI drivers](https://www.msi.com/Laptop/support/GE62-2QD-Apache.html#down-driver&Win10%2064)? (Even if they are not very recent). You could also use a cooling pad.

Answer (score 2):

The MSI GE62-2QD laptop is known for overheating, because its specs were
possibly too ambitious for a laptop with not enough cooling fans or air
passages.

As one [user testimony](https://forum-en.msi.com/index.php?topic=260073.0) says
for a similar model:

> On my machine (GE72 2QF) I find that, when I use 4 heavy processes
>   (which would load 4 physical cores to 100%) I got temperatures in 70s
>   C range and CPU works at maximum frequency of 3.5GHz, but as soon as I
>   put load on other logical cores, temperature rises very rapidly to
>   90+C and CPU starts to throttle to as low as 2.5GHz (and quite
>   honestly, benefits of HT are gone at this point (I mean performance of
>   8 logical cores at 2.5GHz vs performance of 4 physical cores at
>   3.5GHz)).

The usual advice is :

- Hardware : Invest in a cooling pad.
- Windows : In Control Panel -> Power options -> Change plan settings -> Change advanced power settings, expand Processor power management and set the Maximum processor state to 98% for Battery and Plugged in.
  This shouldn't noticeably hurt gaming performance, 
  but should lower the CPU temperature (reduce some more if required).
  You could also try to disable HyperThreading by limiting the number of available processors to Windows (run msconfig in Boot / Advanced options).

Comment: Thank you for submitting an answer. Unfortunately I'm already doing both of the things you mention (limiting cpu power state through a number of different configuration options available to me, and using a high-flow cooling pad). I'll try older driver revisions for any relevant drivers to see if any do not suffer from the power mismanagement that I mentioned before, and keep the bounty open for another day in case a fix comes my way.

Comment: A different driver might make a difference, but I don't believe in it as a complete solution. I think you have a laptop that is running too hot by design, so you will need on the one hand to improve the airflow and on the other to reduce maximal resource usage.